# iOS Convering an Old project to use UI

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xamarin, uiscenedelegate

I am trying to convert (slowly mordenize) an old iOS project to support UISceneDelegate.
However at the moment the old appdelegate creates a UIWindow and attaches a UIViewController to the windows rootViewController in the finishedLaunching.

As I am not ready to convert my application to Storyboards yet is there a way I can achieve the same result using UISceneDelegate ?

Please note the mainViewController is not backed by a XIB or a storyboard so there is no reference to any UI Files in the UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication portion of my info.plist

Regards Christian Stœr Andersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing `Xamairn.iOS`, here is the sample.

Remain the code in `AppDelegate` , and add the following code into `SceneDelegate` .

```cs
[Export ("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    UIWindowScene windowScene = scene as UIWindowScene;
    Window = new UIWindow(windowScene);
    Window.Frame = windowScene.CoordinateSpace.Bounds;
    Window.RootViewController = new YourViewController();
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();            
}
```

Comment: Yes my trouble was with the info.plist file I had to redo the Scene manifest portion